# Regex, FreeSWITCH, match to group #1 second group

Tags: regex, freeswitch

I want to match NA number or a `4443` (voip test)

NA number is classic, no need to think about this:

```
^(?:\+?1)?([2-9]\d\d[2-9]\d{6})$
```

Second part is even easier:

```
^(4443)$
```

Full sequence:

```
^(?:\+?1)?([2-9]\d\d[2-9]\d{6})$\|^(4443)$
```

There are some edge test sequences, including `14443` (optional `[+]1` prefix and `4443` - which returns false, so it is good)

The problem is, if I get an NA number it returned as `%1` (first group)
If input is `4443`, it is a second group.

Is there a way, the group is the same? As much as I understand, there is no named group in FreeSWITCH, though I might be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [branch reset group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html):

```
(?|^(?:\+?1)?([2-9]\d\d[2-9]\d{6})$|^(4443)$)
```

With the pipes escaped for FreeSWITCH:

```
(?\|^(?:\+?1)?([2-9]\d\d[2-9]\d{6})$\|^(4443)$)
```

Now you can refer to either group as `$1` (or `%1` in FreeSWITCH).  A quick look at the docs tells me they use the PCRE library, so this should work.  But I'm sure there are much better ways to do this (including the one in [Vetal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28416354/20938)).

Answer (score 2):

Cheating:

```
   <condition regex="any">
       <regex field="destination_number" expression="^(?:\+?1)?([2-9]\d\d[2-9]\d{6})$"/>
       <regex field="destination_number" expression="^(4443)$"/>
```

Though, how to do it in one regex condition remains unclear.

I'd prefer this way to be in config though, since it is less nerdy and easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

try this: ^(?:+?1)?([2-9]\d\d[2-9]\d{6}|4443)$

but, I don't think that first sequence is correct. Because every pair of (..) is a $.. variable. So you have $1 for (?:+?1), and $2 for [2-9]\d\d[2-9]\d{6} OR 4443.
The idea is to put whole sequence in one pair of parentheses, like so:

^(aaaaaa|bbbbbb)$

with this, you will have one $1 variable, with value "aaaaaa" or "bbbbbb" (what will be matched :)

Comment: ?: is a non-capturing group, it won't count as $ variable


I've thought about ^(aaaaaa|bbbbbb)$ case. 

Though,  (?:+?1) part goes under the group scope and I will have, either +1 prefix (+1 514 234 5678 instead of 514 234 5678). 

Or 14443 as match because of this (1 attributed to (?:+?1), no group but match. And 4443 for the last part)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. Yes, I see 14443 matching problem. Maybe your "cheating" is an only way in this case.